# Time Limits on chargebacks when large company assures me refund is in progress

Tags: credit-card, dispute, chargeback, airline

**Short version:**

Company rep has told me "refund is in progress" for a purchase I made with my credit card, however, it's been over a month, and I have not seen the refund. When or should I try to issue a chargeback in this case?

**Long version:**

I'm dealing with an unfortunate situation with United Airlines. I had some issues with canceled flights in the past, which lead me to receiving flight credit vouchers. Now I have an upcoming need for travel so I decided to use them. They appeared on the web page when purchasing the tickets with the discounted price, however, after clicking checkout, my credit card was charged the full total and the receipt sent to my email also shows no signs of the discount.

Shortly after I reached out to their support chat and after a while I was assured that they would apply the discounts and I should see the amount refunded to my credit card. It didn't appear after a few days so I went back again to support, a total of four times. Each time the answer was the same, the refund was still "processing", except they told me to check in a few days, a week, 20 days, etc. They also refused to send me an official transcript or receipt of this interaction. I copy+pasted the conversation of the chat for my own records but it's disconcerting that I have no official record of what they owe me.

It's now been almost two months. I'm considering filing a chargeback and trying to book with another carrier, because I feel that a simple credit card refund should not take this long and they are just expecting me to forget about it and give up. However, the value of the voucher was substantial (>$1000), so I really don't intend to. I'm concerned if I wait too long, it might go past the point I can perform a chargeback with my credit card carrier (fidelity).

Should I continue waiting, try to contact them yet again, file a dispute, or something else?

Comment: You should check with your credit card issuer, usually disputes are allowed within 2 cycles from the statement on which the original charge appeared